# The error function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I just tried testing if the error function would return an alert but it didn't fire. I altered the url link hoping that it would generate an alert since it won't be able to find or get json data. All I am getting is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined jquery-1.9.1.min.js:3"

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#blogposts', function () {
    //$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();    
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://howtodeployit.com/api/get_recent_po",
        dataType: "json",
        jsonpCallback: 'successCallback',
        async: true,
        beforeSend: function () {
            $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(true);
        },
        complete: function () {
            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data.posts, function (key, val) {
                console.log(data.posts);
                var result = $('<li/>').append([$("<h3>", {
                    html: val.title
                }), $("<p>", {
                    html: val.excerpt
                })]).wrapInner('<a href="#devotionpost" onclick="showPost(' + val.id + ')"></a>');
                $('#postlist').append(result).trigger('create');
                return (key !== 4);
            });
            $("#postlist").listview();
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert("Data not found");
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: async: true, is default.

Comment: afaik $.ajax will only trigger error if the request failes, ignoring the data returned. but i am not sure on this. throw a uncaught exception in your api method to see how your javascript reacts

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that, when you make the AJAX request your code is executing the `success` callback, not the `error` callback. Thus when you execute:

`$.each(data.posts, function(key, val) {`

The `$.each` function is trying to get the length of `data` which is NULL.

It doesn't look right that you have defined a jsonp callback function and yet your still using the `success` and `error` callbacks. This SO question might help a bit :

[Use of success / jsonpCallback with ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167488/use-of-success-jsonpcallback-with-ajax-request)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe here `$.each(data.posts,` data.posts is undefined and that's why you get an error. Log `data` in success callback and see what it contains.

Comment: I think that's the OP's point. If the URL returns 404, the success callback shouldn't be called.

Comment: I would assume so as RGraham had mentioned

Comment: @Chelseawillrecover just try what I said ))

Comment: @karaxuna what change do you want me to make?

Comment: @Chelseawillrecover You can check wheather `data.posts` is undefined or not like this: `if(data.posts) $.each(data.posts, ...`. But I would suggest to see the structure of data object, maybe data.posts is never defined and `data` variable itself contains posts

Comment: @karaxuna data.posts returns fine:
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
 myscript.js:16
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
 myscript.js:16
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
 myscript.js:16
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
 myscript.js:16
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]

Comment: @Chelseawillrecover see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18699968/why-is-my-jquery-plugin-causing-a-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined

Answer (score 0):

I created [a clean Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GcXTA/). Opening the given URL gives a 301 redirect followed by a 200 JSON response. The HTTP status code says that everything is fine, so jQuery doesn't know there was an error.

You mixed up two different concepts here: jQuery's error callback is for network errors and all these things. If you transport error states inside your JSON with HTTP status code 200 you have to deal with it on your own inside the success callback.

Sorry, SO doesn't allow JS-Fiddle links without code:

```
beforeSend: function()  { console.log('beforeSend'); },
complete: function()    { console.log('complete'); },
success:function (data) { console.log('success') },
error: function(data)   { console.log('error') }
```

Comment: Sorry, should hit Save first ;). Updated.

Comment: beforeSend myscript.js:11
error myscript.js:14
complete myscript.js:12
GET http://howtodeployitsdf.com/api/get_recent_po

Comment: The fiddle shows a request to a nonexisting URL and that the error event is fired correclty (at least it does for me, don't know if something is wrong there). However, this is not the case in your example, because your response sends a 200 header. So jQuery won't fire the error event.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your input. I did take on-board all suggestions. Recommendation from Jason seems to had made more sense so while investigating his suggestion I came to this [site](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to read up more about jasonCallback. removing the jasonCallback option though did not fix the issue but strangely this issue seems to do with the url I was using for my json caalback.

What I then did was to change the url from "http://howtodeployit.com/api/get_recent_po" to "http://howtodeployit.com/category/daily-devotion/feed/?json=recentstories" and it worked. Even though both returned error in the console but the second was the one that triggered the error function. Why I am looking into it.